# How to change color of a word in a sentence by clicking it on PC or by touching it on Android

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a game for kids in which I shall hide a word of a sentence by clicking it on PC or by touching it in Android and then reveal the answer by doing the same. I thought of splitting the sentence into array elements and then implement the function that changes color on this sentence. Am I right with this approach ? Thank you all of you in advance.

```html
      <p id="hExample">Hello my world </p>

       <script>
       //Split sentence into array elements
           var jExample = document.getElementById("hExample").innerHTML;
           var jElements = jExample.split(" ");

       //Return array elements into the sentence position
           for (var y=0; y< jElements.length; y++) {
               document.getElementById("hExample").innerHTML += '<span id=' + y + '>' + jElements[y] + " " + "</span> " ;
           }

           document.getElementById('hExample').onclick = changeColor;   

           function changeColor() {
               if ( document.getElementById("hExample").style.color = "white") {
                   document.getElementById("hExample").style.color = "red";
               }else{
                   document.getElementById("hExample").style.color = "white";
               }       
           }   

       </script>
```

Comment: Your code makes sense, but I have one suggestion. Change `style.color = "white"` to `style.opacity = "0"`. This way it will be 'hidden' no matter what the background is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you have an error:

```
document.getElementById('hExample').onclick = changeColor;
```

This sets a click event watcher on the 'hExample' paragraph, but you want to detect clicks on individual spans within 'hExample'. This can be done by checking the `event.target` property, which will equal the clicked span. The code to determine which span was clicked looks like this:

```js
document.getElementById('hExample').addEventListener('click',
  function (event) {
    let spanClicked = event.target;
    // do something with the span
});
```

Here's your code, corrected with a few revisions.

If any of the code is unclear, please ask.

```js
const hExample = document.getElementById('hExample');

// Split sentence into array of words
var jExample = hExample.innerHTML;
var jElements = jExample.split(" ");

// wrap each word in a span
let content = "";
for (var y = 0; y < jElements.length; y++) {
  content += '<span id=' + y + '>' + jElements[y] + " " + "</span> ";
}

// add all spans to hExample
hExample.innerHTML = content;

// listen for clicks inside hExample
hExample.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {

  // get the clicked word
  const word = evt.target;
  
  // add or remove the hidden class
  word.classList.toggle('hidden-span');
  
  // make the word red
  word.style.color = "red";
});
```

```css
/* hide the span */
.hidden-span {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<p id="hExample">Hello my world </p>
```

**Revision — Replace word with underscore when clicked**

A new comment below requests that the clicked word be replaced with an underscore when clicked.

That can be handled easily, using a different method.

See the code below:

```js
  const hExample = document.getElementById('hExample');

  // Split sentence into array of words
  let jExample = hExample.innerHTML;
  let words = jExample.split(" ");

  // wrap each word in a span
  let content = "";
  for (const word of words) {
    content += `<span>${word}</span> `;
  }

  // add all spans to hExample
  hExample.innerHTML = content;

  // handle click on a word
  function handleWordClick (evt) {
    // get the span that was clicked
    const span = evt.target;

    if (span.dataset.word) {
      // extract word from span's 'data-word' attribute and display in red
      span.innerHTML = span.dataset.word;
      delete span.dataset.word;
      span.style.color = 'red';
    } else {
      // maintain current width of span
      span.style.width = span.getBoundingClientRect().width + "px";
      // store word in span's `data-word' attribute
      span.dataset.word = span.innerHTML;
      // show blue "_" in place of word
      span.innerHTML =  "_";
      span.style.color = 'blue';
    }
  }

  // listen for clicks inside hExample
  hExample.addEventListener('click', handleWordClick);
```

```css
span {
  /* this will preserve the span's width */
  display: inline-block;
  /* this will center text inside span */
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p id="hExample">Hello my world </p>
```

Comment: Thank a lot for your comments and the detailed solution you proposed. It works fine.

Comment: May I ask for something else ? Is it possible to implement a function in classList. I am asking that because it would be nice to replace the marked word with a "_" sign in order to know how many words are missing and where exactly to click. I hope you saw this comment. Thank again.

Comment: @Apostolos I added a new version that replaces clicked words with "_", see the answer above.

Comment: Very impressive the way you handle javasript. Anyway, thank you a lot for your time, your effort and your willingness to help me. I tried a lot but I couldn't find a solution. Thank you a lot again !!!

Answer (score 1):

### **Your Problem?**

> Well first off, your if statement contains an `=`. an if statement must be evaluated with an `==`, although you should avoid that, as it doesn't check typing.

This is called *Type Coercion*. More on that here-

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion

You should always try to use `===` when you can. This is represented in the example below.

```
if (x === 9) {
   console.log("x is equal to 9.")
}
```

---

> In newer javscript versions, you should try to use `let` instead of `var`.

---

### **Solution-**

```
<p id="hExample">Hello my world </p>

<script>
    let jExample = document.getElementById("hExample").innerHTML;
    let jElements = jExample.split(" ");

    for (let y = 0; y < jElements.length; y++) {
        document.getElementById("hExample").innerHTML += '<span id=' + y + '>' + jElements[y] + " " + "</span> ";
    }

    document.getElementById('hExample').onclick = changeColor;

    function changeColor() {
        if (document.getElementById("hExample").style.color === "white") {
            document.getElementById("hExample").style.color = "red";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("hExample").style.color = "white";
        }
    }

</script>
```

---

As you can see, the only logic that was wrong, was your if statement.

**Remember:**

Always use `===` and not `=` in your if statements.

Hope this helps!

---

Comment: Thank you a lot for your comments.

Comment: No problem! just glad we could help!