# How to replace a word in a sentence by getBoundingClientRect()

Tags: javascript

Dear all this is an extension of a previous topic ([How to change color of a word in a sentence by clicking it on PC or by touching it on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61759329/how-to-change-color-of-a-word-in-a-sentence-by-clicking-it-on-pc-or-by-touching)). There [stackoverflow.com/users/3113485/terrymorse](http://terrymorse) proposed getBoundingClientRect() in order to replace a word with "_" in a phrase and keep the same width when clicking a word. I am trying to do the same by just replacing the word (WITHOUT CLICKING, JUST A REPLACE) but something goes wrong. Could someone help me.

```
<p id="hExample">This is the phrase I want to change</p>
<p id="hWords">the</p>

<!-- Outcome: This is  _(the same space as "the") phrase I want to change -->

<script>
// Get hExample
const hExample = document.getElementById('hExample');

// Split hExample into array of words
let jExample = hExample.innerHTML;
let jExampleSplit = jExample.split(" ");

// Wrap each word in a span
let content = "";
for (const word of jExampleSplit) {
   content += `<span>${word}</span> `;
}

// Add all spans to hExample
  hExample.innerHTML = content;



// Get hWords
// I am going to split hWords because it may consist of many words, for example "the", "want"
//and need later to loop on them
const hWords = document.getElementById('hWords');

// Split hWords into array of words
let jWords = hWords.innerHTML;
let jWordsSplit = jWords.split(" ");




// I implement @terrymorse idea about getBoundingClientRect()
// Here is where I am mistaken

const span = "the"
span.style.width = span.getBoundingClientRect().width + "px";
// store word in span's `data-word' attribute
span.dataset.word = span.innerHTML;
// show blue "_" in place of word
span.innerHTML =  "_";
span.style.color = 'red';

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set it up so that the words in `hExample` start off hidden if they are in `hWords`. Then you can click on items in `hWords` to show/hide them again.

I added `display: inline-block` to the spans to make sure that the spans actually display with the correct length.

I also added `span.style.borderBottom = '1px solid blue'` to the span instead of an `_` to make the underline show the entire length of the span (rather than a single character)

If you want to hide a specific word in `hExample` from the code, just call `toggleWord` with the argument as the string word you want to hide/show. For example, `toggleWord('change')` would hide the word change. Then you'd call that again to show it again. An example of this is that at the start, I use it to toggle the word 'change' and then I have a timeout that reveals it again after 5 seconds.

```js
// Get hExample
const hExample = document.getElementById('hExample');

// Split hExample into array of words
let jExample = hExample.innerHTML;
let jExampleSplit = jExample.split(' ');

// Wrap each word in a span
let content = '';
for (const word of jExampleSplit) {
  content += `<span style="display: inline-block">${word}</span> `;
}

// Add all spans to hExample
hExample.innerHTML = content;

// Get hWords
// I am going to split hWords because it may consist of many words, for example "the", "want"
//and need later to loop on them
const hWords = document.getElementById('hWords');

// Split hWords into array of words
let jWords = hWords.innerHTML;
let jWordsSplit = jWords.split(' ');

// I implement @terrymorse idea about getBoundingClientRect()
// Toggle any words in hExample that have the same word as the argument
// to this function.
function toggleWord(word) {
  // Get all the children in the phrase.
  const children = hExample.children;
  for (let i = 0; i < children.length; ++i) {
    const span = children[i];
    const spanText = span.dataset.word || span.innerText;
    if (spanText !== word) continue;
    if (span.dataset.word) {
      // extract word from span's 'data-word' attribute and display in red
      span.innerHTML = span.dataset.word;
      delete span.dataset.word;
      span.style.color = 'red';
      span.style.borderBottom = '';
    } else {
      // maintain current width of span
      span.style.width = span.getBoundingClientRect().width + 'px';
      // store word in span's `data-word' attribute
      span.dataset.word = span.innerHTML;
      // show blue "_" in place of word
      /*an.innerHTML = "_";
      span.style.color = 'blue';*/
      // Use a border bottom to make sure it shows the full size of the word.
      span.innerHTML = '';
      span.style.borderBottom = '1px solid blue';
    }
  }
}

// Initially hide all words in hExample that are in hWords.
// This loops over the individual words in hWords and then
// calls toggleWord with the word.
jWordsSplit.forEach((word) => {
  toggleWord(word);
});

// listen for clicks inside hWords
// Then on click, grab the innerText to call toggleWord with.
hWords.addEventListener('click', (evt) => toggleWord(evt.target.innerText));


// toggle the word 'change'
toggleWord('change')
// toggle the word back after 5 seconds
setTimeout(() => toggleWord('change'), 5000);
```

```html
<p id="hExample">This is the phrase I want to change</p>
<p>Click on the words below to show/hide the word in the phrase again</p>
<p id="hWords">the</p>

<!-- Outcome: This is  _(the same space as "the") phrase I want to change -->
```

Comment: I think this is it !!! Thank you so much for your time. Just one question. If I wanted to just replace "the" without clicking, I should write the lines after your "else". But this is not working. What am I missing for just this replacement to work ?

Comment: @Apostolos, I added more details about that within the answer and improved a couple names (handleWordHiding -> toggleWord). You should be able to just call `toggleWord('the')` and it'll toggle the word `the`.

Comment: Yes, now I undestood it. You wrote it very clear. Bravo !!! Thank you a lot again !!!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add an event listener that implements your code when a word is clicked, try the code below, it should work, comment if you still have any issue

```js
// Get hExample
const hExample = document.getElementById('hExample');

// Split hExample into array of words
let jExample = hExample.innerHTML;
let jExampleSplit = jExample.split(" ");

// Wrap each word in a span
let content = "";
for (const word of jExampleSplit) {
  content += `<span>${word}</span> `;
}

// Add all spans to hExample
hExample.innerHTML = content;



// Get hWords
// I am going to split hWords because it may consist of many words, for example "the", "want"
//and need later to loop on them
const hWords = document.getElementById('hWords');

// Split hWords into array of words
let jWords = hWords.innerHTML;
let jWordsSplit = jWords.split(" ");



/* handleWordClick function to change the word to "_" in blue and change the word itself to red
*/

function handleWordClick(evt) {
  // get the span that was clicked
  const span = evt.target;

  if (span.dataset.word) {
    // extract word from span's 'data-word' attribute and display in red
    span.innerHTML = span.dataset.word;
    delete span.dataset.word;
    span.style.color = 'red';
  } else {
    // I implement @terrymorse idea about getBoundingClientRect()

    span.style.width = span.getBoundingClientRect().width + "px";
    // store word in span's `data-word' attribute
    span.dataset.word = span.innerHTML;
    // show blue "_" in place of word
    span.innerHTML = "_";
    span.style.color = 'blue';
  }
}

//onclick run 'handleWordClick'
 hExample.addEventListener('click', handleWordClick);
```

```html
<p id="hExample">This is the phrase I want to change</p>
<p id="hWords">the</p>

<!-- Outcome: This is  _(the same space as "the") phrase I want to change -->
```

Comment: I was misunderstood. I want to replace "the" without clicking. Just replace with same space

Comment: So what should occur for the word to be replaced?

Comment: to be replaced with underscore but the space to be the same as "the". Another instance is to replace the word "change" with underscore but the space to remain the same as in the word "change"