# Replace clickable word with the click sequence

Tags: javascript

I would like to click on some word of a sentence and then the number of the click sequence to replace the clicked word. Next, when I click this number the word to appear again. The problem I face is very strange to me. When I click **right on the number** this number behaves as if it is number, although it is the replacement string, and increases by one. When I press **a little above the number (!!!)** then the word appears normally, as I want it to.

**EXAMPLE**

This is the text I want to work on:

This is  1  text I   2  to work  3 (click on 'the', 'want' and 'on')
This is  1  text I want to work  3 (click on '2')

Please keep in mind that this question is strongly connected with this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/61759785/3716858

```html
    <p id="hExample">This is the text I want to work on</p>
    
    span {
      /* this will preserve the span's width */
      display: inline-block;
      /* this will center text inside span */
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    
    <script>
        // An array to keep the words when they are clicked
        var vArray = [];
        
        const hExample = document.getElementById('hExample');
    
        // Split sentence into array of words
        let jExample = hExample.innerHTML;
        let words = jExample.split(" ");
    
        // wrap each word in a span
        let content = "";
        for (const word of words) {
            content += `<span>${word}</span> `;
        }
    
        // add all spans to hExample
        hExample.innerHTML = content;
    
        // handle click on a word
        function handleWordClick (evt) {
            // get the span that was clicked
            const span = evt.target;
    
            if (span.dataset.word) {
                // extract word from span's 'data-word' attribute and display in red
                span.innerHTML = span.dataset.word;
                delete span.dataset.word;
                span.style.color = 'red';
                
                // When click on number take the word out of the array
                vArray = vArray.filter(item => item !== span.innerHTML);
                
            } else {
                // maintain current width of span
                span.style.width = span.getBoundingClientRect().width + "px";
                // store word in span's `data-word' attribute
                span.dataset.word = span.innerHTML;
                
                // When click on word then bring the word into the array
                vArray.push(span.dataset.word);
                
                // show number in place of word
                span.innerHTML =  vArray.length.toString().fontsize(5);
                span.style.color = 'red';
            }
        }
    
        // listen for clicks inside hExample
        hExample.addEventListener('click', handleWordClick);
    </script>
```

Comment: So, the first part of your requirement is working, but what have you done to try to get the second part working? What is the ***specific*** question/problem, not just a requirement that you need met?

Comment: If I replace span.innerHTML = arr.length.toString(); with span.innerHTML = '-'; it works fine. I do not understand how it happens the string '-' to behave differently than the string 'arr.length.toString()'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your else statement this line:

```
span.innerHTML =  vArray.length.toString().fontsize(5);
```

Converts the span to a <font> tag which cannot access the attribute 'data-word'
so it never enters the first half of the if else.
Moving the .fontsize(5) to a new line with

```
span.style.fontSize = "x-large";
```

should fix that issue

Comment: This is it !!! I would never think of such an answer. Thank you so much !!!

Comment: Dear Scott, thank you very much you too. It is very sound to get deeper to knowledge and learn from others. Thank again a lot for your time and effort for the right explanation.

Comment: You're welcome, it also never hurts to sprinkle in a couple console.logs() and compare the html to what you would expect to see